# Exim no configuration file

Tags: debian, configuration, exim

so I need to find my configuration file for exim. Exim was already installed on my debian dedi, so I didnt install anything, but I cant find the conf file. I found a folder /ect/exim, but all thats in it is a perl folder with a .mdf file in there. Could someone help! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command **exim4 -bV**.  This will show the exim version, what features it supports, and most importantly for you, it will also show where it looks for the configuration file.  The last line should look like this:

```
Configuration file is /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

In Debian, the init script uses configuration macros from /etc/exim4/* to automatically generate the file above.  For more information about this design, look at the two following official pages:

http://wiki.debian.org/Exim

http://pkg-exim4.alioth.debian.org/README/README.Debian.html